# Event fired for plugin updates

Tags: events, updates, octobercms

Is there an Event fired after plugin updates?  I have a script that I want to run to check other plugins for specific changes in their plugin.php file.  I could use the plugin manager to check for these changes in the boot() of my plugin.php file but I don't want to trigger unnecessary code when the only time a change would happen is after a plugin update or install.

For example :

```
Event::listen('app.plugin.update', function($arg1, $arg2) {
// Do something
});
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I am wanting to know if an event exists for plugin updates that I can subscribe to. In my example code I just made up an event string 'app.plugin.update' but I couldn't actually find a string like this in October code.